# Integrating iCalendar in Moodle

Tags: php, icalendar, moodle

I am working on a Moodle project and I have downloaded and installed the latest build(1.9) on my system. I'm using this framework for the very first time so presently trying to get familiar with the environment and the documentation.

My need is to embed an iCal kinda calendar on Moodle's front page using the PHP iCalendar API. I downloaded the latest version of PHP iCalendar but kinda needed some help figuring things out further. I am trying to build a plug-in sorta thing which allows you to put a custom-built calendar (in place of the regular Moodle calendar) on your Moodle site.

Has anyone ever worked with something similar before? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

On moodle.org, there is a change request for this feature in the Moodle Tracker that you might want to follow:

[Calendar: IMPORT or Subscribe to iCal feed into Moodle calendar](http://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-16660)
.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the module development text. It could be fairly easy to do, but I haven't really worked with moodle that much. [http://moodle.org/](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development:Blocks)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently a feature request in Moodle, but may take several version before it comes it becomes a core feature see the feature request here http://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-16660.

The current workaround seems to be to use one of the commonly avaliable web based calendar system to import your ical feed and then inserting a html snippet into moodle to view it.

The obvious example would be to use a public Google calendar to do this but there is also:
http://assignaday.4teachers.org/
http://www.localendar.com/elsie

Reference:
http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=82855